# Why is there no negative sign in the formula of work against electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, work, potential-energy, conventions

Why is there no negative sign in the first formula of work done against electric field where as second formula below has it?

[image]

Comment: It may be a typo. There is a typo in the text itself. Where is this from?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of work is 
$$W_{ab}=\int_{a}^{b}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l}.$$
The electric force is $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$, by substitution 
$$W_{ab}=q\int_{a}^{b}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}.$$
If there is to be a negative sign it will be due to the relative direction of $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{E}$.

In the second formula there is a negative sign because the order of integration is changed, if we want to know the work from a point $P$ to infinity, this is
$$W=q\int_{P}^{\infty}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=-q\int_{\infty}^{P}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$$

Comment: But in the situation described the work is from infinity to the point and not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

In first formula it is not determined what these point-1 and point-2 are. So, to move a charge from point-1 to point-2 can be in the direction of electric field or against the direction of electric field.But in second formula ,we know that infinity is farthest point so clearly we are bringing charge q from infinity to p.It depends on sign of charge also ,but if we take it just q(may be positive or negative) then as force due to electric field is working against the direction of moving the charge,so it will be negative.